# How to create a menu in unity to purchase ammo for my weapons

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am a student currently creating a zombie FPS game using Unity 3D and I simply want to when I press 'E' on the keyboard, I want a menu to pop up and show the prices of the ammo (I have a pistol9mm and an AK) and when I click on buy, the ammo is purchased and I have more ammo.

Is there any helpful suggestions on how I will approach this scenario please ?

Answer (score 0):

So first and most importantly, you have to create the Menu where you are going to buy the ammo from, make the buttons and then script them in a way that when you press them they take money away from the player and then gives him ammo. A single button "Buy ammo" is enough and just a little panel on which the button should stay is needed. After making the menu work, go to the script where you check if the player has pressed the "E" key. Create a new Game Object which holds the Menu where you buy the ammo from and when checking if the player has pressed the "E" key, check if the menu is opened. If it is not, then open the menu, if it is opened, close it. Here is a simple way of doing it.

```
    public GameObject menu;
    private bool isOpen = false;

    void Update(){
        if(Input.GetKeyDown("E")){ //When "E" key is pressed
            if(isOpen == false){    //If the menu is closed, open it
                isOpen = true;
                menu.SetActive(true)
            }else if(isOpen == true){   //If the menu is opened, close it
                isOpen = false;
                menu.SeyActive(false);
            }
        }
    }
```

The way it works is, it either sets the menu to active or unactive when you press the "E" key and it's really simple too. Also when you are done with the Menu set it to active so it doesnt apear on the screen when starting the game, just so it will apear after pressing "E" and so players don't have to close it every time.

I hope i helped you, if you have any questions feel free to ask.